# Name for a particular polyhedron

Tags: geometry

I observed the following polyhedron in the wild and don't know what its name is.

It appears to be two slightly frustrated [hexagonal antiprisms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_antiprism) glued together along their larger-area hexagonal faces so that those vertices coincide, and then hexagonal frustra are glued onto the exposed smaller-area hexagonal faces, again so the glued faces have coincident vertices.

What is a/the precise name for this particular polyhedron?

[image: Polyhedron of interest]

Comment: Check the images here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_uniform_polyhedra and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron It looks like it might be a "snub cube", although I need a less blurry image to be sure.

Comment: I have already done this and it is not one of these polyhedra. It is not a snub cube as there are no rectangular faces.

Comment: You need to either provide a better picture or describe the shape. I'm not playing a guessing game. The current image is too blurry to figure out the details.

Comment: I have described how to construct this shape from two hexagonal antiprisms and two hexagonal frustra in my question body to complement the image. If this is not clear please describe what isn't rather than downvote this question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the ambiguity is with how these triangles are positioned, sorry. What I'm calling a hexagonal antiprism is the article image in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_antiprism. Take two of these and put a pair of their hexagonal faces together. Rotate each about an axis perpendicular to both faces until the vertices of the hexagons align.

Comment: I see now. I didn't know what a Hexagonal anti-prism was. Include that link in the question please.